# How to copy files to a remote machine through a jumping machine by scp command

Tags: ssh, scp

say that the target machine is `user@B.com` and the only place to login is `user@A.com`(usually called jumping machine)
and how can I copy local files to machine **B** using the *scp* command
I've tried `scp files user@B.com` but nothing happens,it only told me sort of *Operation Time Out*

Answer (score 2):

This is what you were looking for:

```
scp -J user@targetMachineA ./local_file_or_directory user@targetmachineB:/path/where/to/copy/
```

from scp man page:

> **-J** destination
> Connect to the target host by first making an scp connection to the **jump host** described by destination and then establishing a TCP
> forwarding to the ultimate destination from there.  Multiple
> jump hops may be specified separated by comma characters.  This is a shortcut to specify a ProxyJump configuration directive.
> This option is directly passed to ssh(1).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the best solution but , you can use the tcp port forwarding feature include in ssh.

first be sure the jumping machine have the Tcp Forwarding enable look into sshd_config file, usually locate in directory "/etc/ssh/" . 
Check if you have the entry:

> AllowTcpForwarding no

By default TcpForwarding is enable, so if it's not disable it's suppose to be ok.

You will establish a connexion on the jumping machine and creation a port fording port locally on your system to communication directly to the system B

the ssh command to run on your workstation will be :

```
ssh -L 2222:server_B:22 server_A
```

from the ssh man page:

> -L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport 
>                Specifies that the given port on the local (client) host is to be forwarded to the given host and port on the remote side. 
>   This works by allocating a socket to listen
>                to port on the local side, optionally bound to the specified bind_address.  Whenever a connection is made to this port,
>   the connection is forwarded over the secure
>                channel, and a connection is made to host port hostport from the remote machine

So to send file to the server B , from your workstation:

```
scp -P 2222 Your_file 127.0.0.1:/PATH_ON_SERVER_B
```

Have a nice day.